# Xcode error- expected declaration in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make something using Swift playgrounds and am confused with auto layouts. I tried to use auto layouts but am ending up with an error "Expected declaration"
Here is my code - I've only added the parts that are relevant

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

public class GameView : UIView{

//    let GameView : UIView!
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 1000))

    }
        GameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



    public override func addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        self.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            ])
    }
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need to learn more about two things - a view controller's "life cycle" or "the sequence of events being fired" and how to use auto layout. (On the latter, I *much* prefer anchor-based code instead of your style, but either should work.) I have one more suggestions involving how *both* of these tie together....

Comment: I see you are placing `GameView` constraints inside `GameView`. While this *may work, why not put these in the `UIViewController` that instantiates `GameView`? If this `UIView` has subviews, **that's** the constraints you want to put inside there. (And please, do it on initialization. No sense in doing repeated work!) It's the view controller that should know things like the size of it's view and the placement of `GameView` in it.And to be honest? Those last 2 constraints make no sense. You're setting `GameView` to be centered too... itself. (At least by the code you posted.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overriding the view's `addConstraints` function but it's never being called. I think if you remove it and add this code to the end of your initialiser it should set up the constraints properly.

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64)
])
```

(The last two constraints, the center X and Y, aren't doing anything because it's constraining the center X of the view to itself. Also I think you mean `self` where you have `GameView.self`)